# HDFS Visulization of block distribution

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, tableau-api

I'm trying to create a visulaization of the HDFS  block distribution of a cluster.

I plan to create this using Tableau but was wondering what type of visualizations would be able to give you an idea of what nodes need re-balancing, and also an efficient way to get the server log data into tableau?

Answer (score 2):

Before investing too much time in this, you might want to take a look at Twitter's open source [HDFS-DU](https://github.com/twitter/hdfs-du) project.  This provides a view of utilization based on paths within the file system rather than DataNodes within the cluster, but perhaps that's still helpful for your requirements.

If the goal is just to identify nodes in need of rebalancing, then this information is already accessible on the NameNode web UI "Datanodes" tab.  You could also run [`hdfs dfsadmin -report`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#dfsadmin) to get utilization stats for each node in a script.

If none of the above meets your requirements, and you need to proceed with integrating the information into an external reporting tool like Tableau, then a helpful integration point might be the JMX metrics exposed via HTTP on the NameNode.  See below for an example `curl` command that queries some of this information from the NameNode.  Note in particular the `LiveNodes` section, which contains capacity information about each DataNode.

Some additional information about these metrics is available in the Apache Hadoop [Metrics](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Metrics.html) documentation.

```
> curl 'http://127.0.0.1:9870/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeInfo'
{
  "beans" : [ {
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeInfo",
    "modelerType" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem",
    "Threads" : 46,
    "Version" : "3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT, rdf497b3a739714c567c9c2322608f0659da20cc4",
    "Used" : 5263360,
    "Free" : 884636377088,
    "Safemode" : "",
    "NonDfsUsedSpace" : 114431086592,
    "PercentUsed" : 5.266863E-4,
    "BlockPoolUsedSpace" : 5263360,
    "PercentBlockPoolUsed" : 5.266863E-4,
    "PercentRemaining" : 88.52252,
    "CacheCapacity" : 0,
    "CacheUsed" : 0,
    "TotalBlocks" : 50,
    "NumberOfMissingBlocks" : 0,
    "NumberOfMissingBlocksWithReplicationFactorOne" : 0,
    "LiveNodes" : "{\"192.168.0.117:9866\":{\"infoAddr\":\"127.0.0.1:9864\",\"infoSecureAddr\":\"127.0.0.1:0\",\"xferaddr\":\"127.0.0.1:9866\",\"lastContact\":2,\"usedSpace\":5263360,\"adminState\":\"In Service\",\"nonDfsUsedSpace\":114431086592,\"capacity\":999334871040,\"numBlocks\":50,\"version\":\"3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT\",\"used\":5263360,\"remaining\":884636377088,\"blockScheduled\":0,\"blockPoolUsed\":5263360,\"blockPoolUsedPercent\":5.266863E-4,\"volfails\":0}}",
    "DeadNodes" : "{}",
    "DecomNodes" : "{}",
    "BlockPoolId" : "BP-1429209999-10.195.15.240-1484933797029",
    "NameDirStatuses" : "{\"active\":{\"/Users/naurc001/hadoop-deploy-trunk/data/dfs/name\":\"IMAGE_AND_EDITS\"},\"failed\":{}}",
    "NodeUsage" : "{\"nodeUsage\":{\"min\":\"0.00%\",\"median\":\"0.00%\",\"max\":\"0.00%\",\"stdDev\":\"0.00%\"}}",
    "NameJournalStatus" : "[{\"manager\":\"FileJournalManager(root=/Users/naurc001/hadoop-deploy-trunk/data/dfs/name)\",\"stream\":\"EditLogFileOutputStream(/Users/naurc001/hadoop-deploy-trunk/data/dfs/name/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000000000862)\",\"disabled\":\"false\",\"required\":\"false\"}]",
    "JournalTransactionInfo" : "{\"MostRecentCheckpointTxId\":\"861\",\"LastAppliedOrWrittenTxId\":\"862\"}",
    "NNStartedTimeInMillis" : 1485715900031,
    "CompileInfo" : "2017-01-03T21:06Z by naurc001 from trunk",
    "CorruptFiles" : "[]",
    "NumberOfSnapshottableDirs" : 0,
    "DistinctVersionCount" : 1,
    "DistinctVersions" : [ {
      "key" : "3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT",
      "value" : 1
    } ],
    "SoftwareVersion" : "3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT",
    "NameDirSize" : "{\"/Users/naurc001/hadoop-deploy-trunk/data/dfs/name\":2112351}",
    "RollingUpgradeStatus" : null,
    "ClusterId" : "CID-4526ea43-52e6-4b3f-9ddf-5fd4412e322e",
    "UpgradeFinalized" : true,
    "Total" : 999334871040
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million Chirs, that was very helpful. To be specific my requirements, they were to create a  visulization of data block distribution in order to better understand how data is distributed. If that generates any new ideas for you, please let me know! All help is appreciated!